# One page wizard using angular formly

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-formly

I'm creating form using angular formly with more than 50 fields and i have displayed fields using Advance layout. ([link](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout))

Now the form is so big and i want to divide it in small parts. 
How can i 
achieve one page wizard (eg- [Sample Pattern](http://patternry.com/p=one-page-wizard/) ) using angular formly?

Or is there any other best way to show such big form in user friendly manner using angular formly? Please Suggest.

Another issue that i'm facing is most of the fields in the form are select field and data in this select field is coming from server. So the form is taking some time to load. How can i reduce the loading time of form?

Comment: For wizard, refer http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/angular-wizard

Comment: @ Rajagopal-Thanks for the reply. I'm  looking for one page wizard . The link you have suggested is for multi page wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use 
http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout

and break up the form into a step manner for user friendly form.

I don't think formly-form takes time in rendering (negligible). You might need to tweak your server api to return data soon.